# Is it possible to inspect which nodes are connected to your node via rpc or polakdot.js?

Tags: networking, libp2p

I am trying to get some information about the (other) nodes that are connected to my parachain node.

I can see how many nodes are connected ( in telemetry and polkadotjs apps), but how can I find their network identities? Can I query this information via RPC or polkadot js? If so how?

Answer (score 4):

You can get that information from the RPC call `system.peers()`.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Should I also note that port 9933 should be open on the ui node to execute this action?

Comment: :9944 for websockets. The hosted apps UI cannot make connections to `ws://` [endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866696/connecting-to-ws-websocket-unsecure-in-https-site), so if using that you would need to place it behind a nginx proxy with a certificate.